# How to count items in a chest in Java edition 1.18, using /execute if?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating an escape room in Java Minecraft 1.18 and want the player to put 23 torches in a chest that's standing on top of a repeating command block.
I want this command block to teleport the player to the coordinates (0, 128, 0) as soon as the chest has exactly 23 torches in it.
**Is that possible in Java 1.18 using the /execute command?** I've already read [Question 211257: Counting items in a chest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211257/counting-items-in-a-chest) but /testforblock doesn't exist in Java 1.18...

Comment: On Arqade we generally expect old questions to be kept up to date rather than re-asked. So I've posted an [updated answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395774/185203) to [Counting items in a chest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211257/counting-items-in-a-chest), and am now voting to close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @pppery Oh, I didn't find a question that exactly asked for counting chest's items using the /execute command... But thanks for answering my question below that other question ;)